# Isoperimetry in $\mathbb{Z}^{d}$.

Tags: analysis, inequality

I came across the following statement:

For any finite $S \subset \mathbb{Z}^{d}$, there exists $i \in \lbrace 1,\cdots,d\rbrace$ such that
$\begin{align*}
|P_{i}\left(S\right)| \geq |S|^{\frac{2}{3}}.
\end{align*}$ where $P_{i}$ be the projeciton on the hyperplane $H_{i}(0) := \lbrace \sum_{i \neq j} k_{j}e_{j} : k_{j} \in \mathbb{Z}^{d}\rbrace$.

A well-known statement in this direction would be the "Discrete Loomis and Whitney Inequality". Try to come up with a counterexample, as the proof was also flawed. Does anyone have any idea how I could construct a counterexample for this?

Comment: I've edited it, thanks for mentioning it!